# How to grey out item in a Checked List Box

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have a checked list box that displays a number of items. Some items in the box should be disabled but visible (depending on the state of a couple of radio buttons).

I have been able to disable them so that you cannot check or uncheck them, by using the ItemCheck event handler, so that's not a problem.

All I need now is to find a way to grey out the items. 
I did try this:

```
myCheckedListBox.SetItemCheckState(index, CheckState.Indeterminate)
```

This makes the item checkbox grey BUT checked. I need it to be grey and either checked or unchecked, depending on the state of the item.

Is there a way to change the appearance of a single item in a CheckedListBox

Answer (score 5):

You have to create your own `CheckedListBox` like this:

```
public class CustomCheckedList : CheckedListBox
{
    public CustomCheckedList()
    {
        DisabledIndices = new List<int>();
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
    public List<int> DisabledIndices { get; set; }
    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDrawItem(e);
        Size checkSize = CheckBoxRenderer.GetGlyphSize(e.Graphics, System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.MixedNormal);
        int d = (e.Bounds.Height - checkSize.Height) / 2;                        
        if(DisabledIndices.Contains(e.Index)) CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, new Point(d,e.Bounds.Top + d), GetItemChecked(e.Index) ? System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.CheckedDisabled : System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.UncheckedDisabled);
    }
    protected override void OnItemCheck(ItemCheckEventArgs ice)
    {
        base.OnItemCheck(ice);
        if (DisabledIndices.Contains(ice.Index)) ice.NewValue = ice.CurrentValue;
    }
}
//To disable the item at index 0:
customCheckedList.DisableIndices.Add(0);
```

You may want to use another type of structure to store disabled indices because the `List<>` I used in my code is not OK, it can contain duplicated indices. But that's for demonstrative purpose. We just need a way to know which items should be disabled to render accordingly.