# Make specific checkboxes visible in a ListVew

Tags: c#, winforms

**Example:**

Having a list of tasks pending, and each task is a row in a listView with a checkbox.

Is it possible when the task is done & checked to make the checkbox invisible for
the specific task and keep the record of course ?

thank you.

[image]

Comment: could you please explain more like with examples.

Comment: I guess you would be stuck here, you may have to draw the items yourself, here is a reference link for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144468/how-to-grey-out-item-in-a-checked-list-box/17145896#17145896 . It's for `CheckedListBox`, not for `ListView` but the idea is the same. You can also try searching first, I doubt there should be some helpful samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give every `ListViewItem` a `property` ID and in the checkboxes as well. And if the `Checkbox` belongs to the `ListViewItem` and if the task is done and if the checkbox is checked you can hide this checkbox. If I understood you right, is this the code you need:

```
public class ListViewItemID : ListViewItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
public class CheckBoxID : CheckBox
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
public class program
{
    void Main()
    {
        var itemOne = new ListViewItemID { ID = 1 };
        var itemTwo = new ListViewItemID { ID = 2 };
        var checkBoxOne = new CheckBoxID { ID = itemOne.ID };
        checkBoxOne.CheckedChanged += HideCheckBox;
        var checkBoxTwo = new CheckBoxID { ID = itemTwo.ID };
        checkBoxTwo.CheckedChanged += HideCheckBox;
    }
    void HideCheckBox(object item, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (item.GetType() == typeof(CheckBoxID))
        {
            var checkBoxID = (CheckBoxID)item;

            foreach (ListViewItemID lItem in listViewItems.Where(lItem => lItem.ID == checkBoxID.ID && lItem.Text == "done" && checkBoxID.Checked))
            {
                checkBoxID.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        else if (item.GetType() == typeof(ListViewItemID))
        {
            var lItem = (ListViewItemID)item;
            foreach (var checkBox in Controls.Where(ctrl => ctrl.GetType() == typeof(CheckBoxID)).Select(ctrl => (CheckBoxID)ctrl).Where(checkBox => checkBox.ID == lItem.ID && checkBox.Checked && lItem.Text == "done"))
            {
                checkBox.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the parent of the `CheckBox`?

Comment: @KingKing I think he is using the standard `Windows.Forms.Button` - which is NOT `ListViewItem`.
I don't see how this answer solves the problem. And the endless loop thing sounds like a bad practice.